# Can we configure ADFS as token endpoint for Azure

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, adfs

I am trying to set up a central authorization server for my multiple application . Has any one tried setting up ADFS (any version)  as token generator for multiple resource provider like Azure AD , Salesforce , Workday

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple applications in ADFS as a relying party.

Each application will be added as a relying party. Get metadata from the application end and configure it. Please refer is [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-relying-party-trust).